# Run a bash called from php and return a string

Tags: php, bash

Hello I have the following PHP function:

```
public function index()
{        
  $return_var = exec('/home/iosef/createinstanceinfolder.sh');
  print_r($return_var);
}
```

Which is calling the following bash script in ubuntu 20.04:

```
#!/bin/bash

$my_array=(foo bar)
$my_array[0]=foo
```

How can I return this array to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exec takes 2 more parameters.

try:

```
  $return_var = exec('/home/iosef/createinstanceinfolder.sh', $output, $retval);
```

Then `print_r($output);`

Also `$output` basically returns everything **displayed** by your script so  in your script echo as a json or print_r your array  in the end